# Possible hard drive failure

Tags: hard-drive, memory, hardware-failure, cpu-usage

If several system processes seem to freeze, while CPU and Memory usage remain low, does this suggest hard drive failure?

Comment: yes, no, maybe, could be. What else is going on? Are there any significant errors in the event log (assuming windows). What processes? What do you mean by froze up? What diagnostics have you run? There really isn't enough information in the question to give a definitieve answer.

Comment: System slowness/freezes are also related to poor performing Windows Services (many times virus scan software that's corrupted that needs reinstalling).  A high rate of interups will also do this.

Comment: Could be some kernel space locking problem or hard disk. Was the hard disk LED constantly on when your system is frozen? What is the SMART status of the disk? What operating system?

Comment: @Cody, please add some details, or there is a very good chance that the question will be closed.

Answer (score 1):

Probably not. Other symptoms would likely creep up before system processes freeze, and if this is your only symptom it could be indicative of many different problems.

But it can't hurt to make sure. Run a chkdsk at the command prompt and any HDD testing included in your system. While these tests won't 100% prove that your HDD is fine, it's a quick and easy way to convince yourself to start looking elsewhere for the problem.

Try running sfc /scannow at the command prompt to check the integrity of Windows. (Note that this test isn't 'all inclusive' either.)